# Core Audio on iOS detect system speaker has any output

Tags: ios, core-audio, volume, waveform, speaker

I am new in Core Audio Programming.

I try to do the automation test on the voice streaming app.  Unfortunately, we are using 3rd party lib which get the audio streaming and directly output to system output device (e.g. iPhone speaker).  I like to have a test that draw the histogram (wave graph) for the speaker volume to reflect that is really get output from the internet stream.   Anyone can provide some suggestion, hints, sample code, opensource to get the output device realtime info such as volume, pitch etc...?

Comment: Are you wanting to draw a peak wave that represents the output samples in real time?

Comment: Does this have something to do with Cisco? If not, why is "IOS" in the title?

Comment: @H2CO3: Didn't Cisco sell the rights to some product names to Apple?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Hehh :D I don't know. The only thing I know is that "iOS" and "IOS" are completely different things.

Comment: Bamsworld: Yes... It is what I want.  Anyway to achieve?

Comment: interman - This all depends on whether you have source code for 3rd party library? If not ,then it may require writing code to handle streaming yourself and not use 3rd party lib. Does the 3rd party lib offer any way to intercept the stream? Please put @Bamsworld in comment next time so I get notified in inbox. Providing you have access to the bytes in the stream it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try plugging the headphone output of the device-under-test into the audio input of another Mac, PC or iOS device to acquire audio test/histogram data.  Or just put a Mac/PC external mic next to the DUTs speaker.